# Trying to locate information on alpha particle scattering/peak resonance energies for elements

Tags: nuclear-physics

On our campus we have an ion beam analysis lab. It is used for compositional analysis through the firing of alpha particles at MeV energies at target samples. From here it is a simple matter of back scattering kinematics to calculate atomic masses thereby giving the general composition of the test samples.

There are many cases for overlap of the peaks in channels and to compensate some tables have been provided by the lab for finding scattering (peak) resonances of certain elements to increase mass resolution, however it is by no means complete.

It would be helpful to have a more thorough listing of elements/alpha particle scattering resonance energies; my search has so far proven futile. Does anyone have a link or know of a good resource for this information?

Answer (score 1):

While there are some resonances in alpha backscattering (e.g. on oxygen-16 at 3.05 MeV) most analysis labs use lower energies (1-2 MeV) in order to (a) avoid those resonances and thus get results from a wide range of elements using simple kinematics aka Rutherford backscattering, and (b) to get better depth resolution because the rate of energy loss with depth goes like 1/E and is therefore higher at lower energies. Rather than being caused by resonances in the elastic cross section, the peaks you are seeing are probably due to the structure of the sample. Ion backscattering is usually used on samples that consist of thin layers, such as the metallization on integrated circuits. A thin layer of something on a lighter substrate (e.g. Ni on a Si substrate) will give a peak in the backscattered energy spectrum.

I think it would be difficult to analyze a backscatter spectrum with just a table of peak positions. That's only going to work if the layers are very thin and right on the surface of the sample. But you can calculate your own table of kinematic factors easily -- just Google for the formula. You'll need to know the angle between the detector and the beam in your experimental setup. The scattering angle to plug into the formula for kinematic factor is usually something like 160 or 170 degrees, something like that.

For complex samples you will need a simulation program. I used to use RUMP, but there are others. It is also usual to know something about the composition of the sample, but it sounds as if in your case you are being asked to identify the elements present. If the peaks you see are wider at half-maximum than the detector resolution of (say) 10 keV then they are broadened by energy loss in the sample, so you need to use the high-energy edge of the peak (ie collisions that took place at the surface) rather than the highest point to find the mass of the target atoms.

Comment: It's not so much for compositional analysis as it is about trying to use resonant energies to help 'see' certain elements in the sample. Much like you pointed out oxygen at 3.05MeV (my book says 3.06:) we get a nice 'spike'. Barry's machine has tandem accelerators and can go to 5.2MeV. This is enough to overcome the Coulombic threshold up to fluorine, although that is a separate topic.

Comment: RUMP never incorporated non-Rutherford cross sections in a clean way, partly because they could be highly scattering geometry dependent. SimNRA does incorporate resonances, but I think it becomes much more complex, particularly for a beginner.  Not that there are many beginners anymore for RBS...

Comment: @Jon Custer, I'm a proud beginner.

Answer (score 1):

The data you have requested are voluminous. There are many such resonances for each combination of incident particle and nucleus (well, some of the very light nuclei have only a few, but they are the exception).

Various agencies compile experimental data and publish them as Evaluated Nuclear Data Files (ENDF), which can be found [at the National Nuclear Data Center](http://www.nndc.bnl.gov/), and probably elsewhere around the web.

These are intended to be a expert best guess combination of the available data and in most cases they are the basis of the cross-sections used by major simulations.

The big problems are finding the ones of interest to you and then digging out the interesting features from them.

---

I have had the experience on collecting and reconciling the various papers on a particular reaction (which took me weeks) and later comparing my result to those in a ENDF.  In that case the file and I were in good agreement even in the hard places. I suspect that the people who do this really know their stuff.

Comment: I have been looking through the data base and am having a difficult time locating anything with alpha particle projectiles (plenty on HE3 and smaller), am I perhaps looking in the wrong place?

Answer (score 0):

The most recent handbook available is 'Ion Beam Analysis: Fundamentals and Applications' edited by Mike Nastasi et al. I have not used that one.  Another that may still be available is the 'Handbook of Modern Ion Beam Materials Analysis' edited by Joe Tesmer et al. I have that one on my shelf.  There are various older, classic texts such as Jim Mayer's.  All have section on nuclear reaction analysis and at least some info on cross sections. Frankly, I'm surprised that one or the other isn't readily available near the accelerator console!

A further option is to get a hold of a copy of SimNRA, the most recent program used to interpret RBS, NRA, ERD, ... data - it has the non-Rutherford cross-sections built in.

For a collection of cross section data, visit [IAEA Cross section page](http://www-nds.iaea.org/ibandl/).

Have fun!

Comment: Surprisingly I have been unable to find that book in our library catalog. We recently had a flood and things have been a little messy since then, perhaps that is at issue. There likely are more resources available in the lab, however it is always good to be well prepared ahead of time. Thank you for the link, this should keep me busy for the time being.