# File with particle decay data

Tags: particle-physics, resource-recommendations, software, data-analysis, data

Does anyone know of a computer parsable file that has basic physics and decay data for (quite many) observable particles, such as mesons, barions, heavy leptons and $W, Z, H$?

To clarify the data I am looking for is something like:
name, charge, mass, half-life, branching ratios and decay products

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it looks like it's about a software recommendation.

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/221040/520 https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/371664/520  https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/185924/520 https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/33520/520 https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/14649/520

Answer (score 0):

They are in the [PDG](http://pdg.lbl.gov/2018/listings/contents_listings.html), which is not super easy to parse. [Here](http://fstate.org/howto-search) is a project I worked on before that has some of that information based on an internal document from LHCb, it is a bit more scrape-able.